# search through a file with list of elements in an array using shell

Tags: shell

I have a list of elements in an array (eg. xml tags) and if I were to search them through a list of files and extract matching lines to a temp file.What is a good way?

here's what I tried in a script:

```
myArray =(ZZ1 BZ1 ZZ2 AZ1 AZ2)

echo "${myArray[@]}"

while read line
do
 if [[ "$line" =~ ${myArray[@]} ]];then
       echo $line | awk -F "[><]" '{print $2"|"$3}'
fi
done < file.xml
```

Thanks all for the information:

But the below comparison -- "$line" =~ $regex is scanning through the file and fetching all the data along with the data that im looking.how to filter them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script will search through `file.xml` looking for any occurrence of any of the strings in `myArray`:

```
#!/bin/bash
myArray=(ZZ1 BZ1 ZZ2 AZ1 AZ2)

regex="$(echo "(${myArray[@]})" | sed 's/ /|/g')"

while read line
do
 if [[ "$line" =~ $regex ]];then
       echo $line | awk -F "[><]" '{print $2"|"$3}'
fi
done < file.xml
```

Since `=~` does a regular expression match, the key change above was to convert `myArray` into a suitable regular expression: `(ZZ1|BZ1|ZZ2|AZ1|AZ2)`.

Since the question provides neither sample input from `file.xml` nor desired output, I don't know if the awk command does what you want or not.

Comment: But the above comparison -- "$line" =~ $regex is scanning through the file and fetching all the data along with the data that im looking.how to filter them?

Comment: @user3290453 It should not do that.  Could you try adding the line `echo $regex` to your script and verify that the regex looks like mine above.  And, if so, then show me what kind of line it lets through that you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need loop in shell, can do that in awk itself.

```
myArray=(ZZ1 BZ1 ZZ2 AZ1 AZ2)
re=$(printf "%q|" "${myArray[@]}")

awk -F "[><]" -v re="(${re%|*})" '$0 ~ re {print $2"|"$3}' file.xml
```